# Evaluating a limit using a graph

Tags: calculus, limits

How would you even attempt to answer a question such as:

Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n+2}\right)... + \left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$

And the given hint is "Hint: Graph sketching can help you and you may use the relation $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f\left(\frac{an + b}{cn + d}\right) = f\left(\frac{a}{c}\right) $$

When $f$ is continuous and $a,b,c$ and $d$ are reals with $ c \neq 0$

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The hint seems worse than useless.

Comment: @zhw. I'm groping to see how the hint facilitates this.  So .... worse than useless describes it better than perfectly ... ;-)

Comment: May I ask where is this "hint" from?

Comment: This is a question from an undergraduate CSAT exam for computer science at Cambridge. The hint is given in the question. @Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{k+n}\\\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+k/n}\tag1
\end{align}$$

where $(1)$ is the Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\,dx=\log(2)$.

---

Alternatively, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k -\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac1{2k}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac1{2k}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{k}\tag2
\end{align}$$

where we recognize the limit of $(2)$ as $n\to \infty$ as the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ evaluated at $x=1$.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \ln n + \gamma + o(1)$ where $\gamma \approx 0.577$ is Euler's constant; so $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} = (\ln(2n) + \gamma + o(1)) - (\ln n + \gamma + o(1)) = \ln 2 + o(1)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: this is worth a separate answer

Comment: @DanielSchepler Sure, but that is complete overkill here and quite unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry if this seems like a trivial question, but what is the difference between using Riemann's sum and just doing a definite integration to get a much more accurate answer?

Comment: The limit of a Riemann sum is equal to the definite integral.

Comment: If so, why is not advised to use a definite integral instead of a Riemann sum

Comment: They are equal and we can evaluate the Riemann sum by evaluating the integral that it represents.

Answer (score 1):

Not using the hint, but Riemann sums instead:
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k/n} \to
\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x}\; dx = \ln 2.
$$

Comment: The limits on the integral should be $1$ and $2$, not $1/2$ and $1$.